# Play two soundfiles at the same time with USB soundcard

Tags: audio

I have a raspberry with 1 USB connected to a USB Soundcard 5.1. The USB soundcard is set as default, and I can play a sound from terminal using MPlayer:

```
mplayer --channels=6 soundTest.aif
```

It can be executed in background with this command (not very sure of what it does, a normal & at the end doesnt work):

```
mplayer --channels=6 soundTest.aif < /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If I try to execute this command in two different terminal screens at the same time, the second one doesnt play and basically I have this explanation:

> failed (-16): Device or resource busy

How can I play 2 sounds at the same time?

EDIT: Seems to work when using the Raspberry headphones jack

Comment: It looks like the mixer in your sound card doesn't have 12 channels available. Can you post your `mplayer.conf`?

Comment: Damn... 12 channels? Isnt it a little overkill? Anyway, the config file of path home/py/.mplayer/config is empty (it only says "add your config here")

Answer (score 1):

```
omxplayer -o alsa ring.wav
```

Omxplayer is able to play several surround files at the same time with the USB SoundCard (using different terminal windows). It only needs to have the USB Soundcard selected as default in usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf

This last thing in my case is:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```